# Upload video files in BLOB storage SharePoint 2013

Tags: blob

Can we configure SharePoint so that anytime when a video file is uploaded to SharePoint server it should physically save in a remote storage and not within SharePoint?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.petri.co.il/install-configure-remote-blob-storage-rbs-sharepoint-farm.htm#

Comment: No this link is showing configuring of BLOB, I want to restrict other extension rather than video files.

Comment: Take a look at SharePoint Blob Cache http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261797(v=office.15).aspx. Maybe this will help. I'm not sure that you can configure it to remote server though.

Comment: You got a -1 because of the overload of my spellchecker.

Comment: Just wondering if you could set up one content DB to use RBS and use Content Organizer to route media files from drop off library(ies) straight to
library in site collection that has RBS set up :)

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out if we can manage this to work: RBS with Content Organizer. Any help on this subject?

Answer (score 5):

The Microsoft Remote Blob Storage doesn't have the ability to only upload certain file types, but since most videos are very large files, you can configure RBS to only put files of a certain size into blob storage.

Here's the nitty gritty of it:  Since sharepoint 2013 now shreds all blobs into smaller pieces, you video files will be automatically taken apart and put into chunks of 1MB (whereas office documents are put into tiny shreds of 65KB or less). So to get all those large chunks into blob storage, but leave your office docs in SharePoint, you can set the minimum blob storage size to something greater the the blob size of the office docs.

We've set ours to 67KB.  Here's the code in powershell to do that:

```
$cdb = Get-SPContentDatabase Name_of_Content_DB
$rbs = $cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
$rbs.MinimumBlobStorageSize = 67584 #value in bytes
$rbs.Update()
```