# Big Video Files on Sharepoint 2013 More then 52 MB

Tags: video

I want to ask a Question how to ad big Video files with more then 52 Mega Bytes. How Could I put this big files to Sharepoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow this:

[What is the File Size limit in Upload Multiple Documents functionality?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108873/what-is-the-file-size-limit-in-upload-multiple-documents-functionality)

central admin -> application managment -> manage web applications -> select a web application you want to change -> within the tab above select general settings -> within the popup scroll down till you get to 'Maximum Upload Size'.

the default is 50MB, the max if i remember right is 2GB. Be it for one file or 500 files, it calculates it all as a combined ammount.

example:

1) i set size limmit to 2GB, i have 90 files and totaling 1.5GB

that would upload fine as its under 100 files and the total combined size of 90 files is under 2GB.

2) i set size limmit to 2GB, i have 105 files and totaling 1.5GB

this will fail as it surpasses 100 file limit. The file size is still fine tho as its 1.5GB and max is 2GB. To get this working I would break the file ammount to two bulk uploads or use explorer view on the document library.

in your case your asking about uploading one file at 500mb within multiple upload form and you have set a max of 1GB upload limit.

as its a big single file have you set the web application web.config properly?

find and set it to this:

the above code is setting the upload limit for iis to 901.2 MB, giving the timeout a bit longer to execute due to the large upload aswell! set above accordingly (close to 500 mb mark)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx

or this:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sammykailini/archive/2013/11/06/how-to-increase-the-maximum-upload-size-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

more info on the subject of max limmits set on sharepoint and why:

> Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: And how to make BLOB database. Can I set a Database in that way that files more then in example 60 MB put for BLOB Database.

Comment: yes its already answered here ;), refer to cam's answer http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96874/upload-video-files-in-blob-storage-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0):

From Technet Article:

In SharePoint Server 2013, there are certain limits that are by design and cannot be exceeded, and other limits that are set to default values that may be changed by the farm administrator. There are also certain limits that are not represented by a configurable value, such as the number of site collections per web application.

Boundaries are absolute limits that cannot be exceeded by design. It is important to understand these limits to ensure that you do not make incorrect assumptions when you design your farm.
An example of a boundary is the 2 GB document size limit; you cannot configure SharePoint Server 2013 to store documents that are larger than 2 GB. This is a built-in absolute value, and cannot be exceeded by design.

Thresholds are those that have a default value that cannot be exceeded unless the value is modified. Thresholds can, in certain circumstances, be exceeded to accommodate variances in your farm design, but it is important to understand that doing this may affect the performance of the farm in addition to the effective value of other limits.

The default value of certain thresholds can only be exceeded up to an absolute maximum value. A good example is the document size limit. By default, the default document size threshold is set to 250MB, but can be changed to support the maximum boundary of 2GB.

Rising this limit needs to be done both in Central Administration and Web.config file (edit with notepad).

However, take into consideration the weight on the network when all those files are streaming simultaneously.

The standard size is 250 so I do not understand why you cannot upload a 52 MB.